# It's possible select a row of dataTable in Primeng with mouseover event

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

In the doc primeng it puts for select a row this => 'In single mode, a row is selected on click event of a row' and add the event (onRowSelect) but it is only invoked with the click event, exist any function to select the row with over event?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an event listener for `mouseover`, which is the same as using the DOM object event `onmouseover`.

```
<div (mouseover)="selectRow($event)">
```

or something like that

Edit: In PrimeNG context,

```
<p-column (mouseover)=selectRow($event)>Stuff</p-column>
```

Comment: where you put this <div> tag inside the p-dataTable?

Comment: I just wanted to give an example. You can use the row definition instead.